# A few clarifications regarding convolutional neural networks

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

When reading about the transforming the fully connected layer into convolutional layer, posted in http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/#convert.

I just feel confused about the following two comments:

> It turns out that this conversion allows us to "slide" the original ConvNet very efficiently across many spatial positions in a larger image, in a single forward pass.

A standard ConvNet should be able to work on any size image. The convolutional filter can slide across the image grid, so why do we need to slide the original ConvNet in any spatial positions in a larger image?

And

> Evaluating the original ConvNet (with FC layers) independently across 224x224 crops of the 384x384 image in strides of 32 pixels gives an identical result to forwarding the converted ConvNet one time.

What does "strides of 32 pixels" mean here? Does that refer to the filter size? When talking about 224*224 crops of the 384*384 image, does that mean we use a receptive field of 224*224?

I marked these two comments as red in the original context.

[image]

Comment: You need to read up on ConvNet. Stride means jump size.  "When the stride is 1 then we move the filters one pixel at a time. When the stride is 2 (or uncommonly 3 or more, though this is rare in practice) then the filters jump 2 pixels at a time as we slide them around. This will produce smaller output volumes spatially." source : http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fully connected layers can only deal with input of a fixed size, because it requires a certain amount of parameters to "fully connect" the input and output. While convolutional layers just "slide" the same filters across the input, so it can basically deal with input of an arbitrary spatial size.

In the example network with fully-connected layers at the end, a 224*224 image will output an 1000d vector of class scores. If we apply the network on a larger image, the network will fail because of the inconsistency between the input and parameters of the first fully-connected layer.

One the other hand, if we use a fully convolutional network, when applied to a larger image we'll get 1000 "heatmaps" of class scores.

As shown in the following figure (from the [FCN segmentation paper](http://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jonlong/long_shelhamer_fcn.pdf)), the upper network gives one score per class, and after the conversion (convolutionalization), we can get the a heatmap per class for a larger image.
[image]

About "stride", on the same page, in the section Spatial arrangement:

> When the stride is 1 then we move the filters one pixel at a time. When the stride is 2 (or uncommonly 3 or more, though this is rare in practice) then the filters jump 2 pixels at a time as we slide them around. This will produce smaller output volumes spatially.

Comment: thank you very much for the reply. I have two more questions regarding your answer: 1) Regarding your statement of  “If we apply the network on a larger image, the network will fail because of the inconsistency between the input and parameters of the first fully-connected layer.” Can you elaborate more? For instance, the original image size is 224*224, the parameters of the first fully-connected layer is 4096, why they are consistent? ( I have to put the second question in the another comment due to the length constraints.)

Comment: this the second question regarding your answer. Thanks.2) My confusion about “ across 224x224 crops of the 384x384 image in strides of 32 pixels” is that does it mean we let filter jump 32 pixels, why we need that large jump? For this 384*384 image, does that mean we will use a receptive field of “224*224”?

Comment: @user3269 if the input of the fully-connect layer is 7*7*512, we'll need 7*7*512*4096 parameters to "fully connect" the input and the output. if the spatial size of the input increases, we'll need more parameters. for convolutional layers we just apply the same filter to every part of the input.

Comment: @user3269 the network output one value per class for 224*224 images, when we feed in a 384*384 image, it will output a 12*12 heatmap for each class,  each pixel of the heatmap is equivalent to the value we get by applying the network on a 224*224 patch in a specific location. because the network reduces the spatial size of he input by a factor of 32 (224*224->7*7), so sliding by one pixel in the top layer is sliding by 32 pixels in the input image.

Comment: dontloo, thanks for your reply. Just for clarification, you mentioned 12*12 heatmap, should it be 6*6 heatmap?  Secondly,  there are a lot of combinations of applying 224*224 patch against 384*384. On the other side, heatmap only has 6*6, how can we match one pixel of the heatmap to the operation of “applying the network on a 224*224 patch in a specific location”

Comment: @user3269 right, it should be 6*6 sorry. I see what you mean, take a 2*2 pooling layer as an analogy, when given a 4*4 input, the output will be a 2*2 map where each element is the result of a 2*2 patch of the input. But not every 2*2 patch is involved (e.g. the patch right at the center of the input), the elements next to each other in the output map are actually generated by patches 2 pixels away in the input. Maybe it would help if you imagine the whole network as some 32*32 pooling layer.

Comment: @user3269 and of course not all the possible 224*224 patches are reflected in the results, most of those are skipped.

Comment: I really appreciate your answering my questions.

Comment: @user3269 you're so welcome

Comment: what if we "slide" on some larger input size with a fc cnn, we could still get a "heatmap". If so, what's the point of a fully conv network?

Comment: @flankechen hi, if I understood correctly, sliding an entire cnn to get a heatmap is less efficient since there will be large overlaps among different windows sent into the network, and we will end up applying the same set of filters to these overlapping regions repeatedly. A better choice is to save such redundancy and apply the network to the entire image once, and that can be done by a fully convolutional network.

Comment: @dontloo thanks for the reply, but for a fully conv network, we just still "slide" it over the input, am I right? if we config the stride carefully, a fully connected network could perform similar to fully conv network?

Comment: @flankechen for fully conv networks send the entire image into the network and slide the convolution filters which is more efficient than sliding the whole network, apart from that I think a fully connected network would work as well.

Comment: @dontloo if I wanted to use an FCN to classify input images of different sizes, then do I need to collapse the MxMx4096 heatmaps (e.g. via avg. pooling, max pooling, or other) to produce a 1x1x4096 volume and then apply a conv layer which has N filters (where each filter is size 1x1x4096) to produce a  1x1xN volume where N is the # of classes?

Comment: @user3731622 yea, that sounds a viable solution, and we can apply the 1*1*n conv layer first followed by global pooling as well.